# Determine C# P/Invoke Structure Alignment at Runtime

Tags: c#, pinvoke, setupapi

I'm trying to write good P/Invoke signatures for some Windows setupapi calls, and I've encountered the following problem with the packing of setupapi's structures:

```
// Excerpt from setupapi.h
#if defined(_WIN64)
#include <pshpack8.h>   // Assume 8-byte (64-bit) packing throughout
#else
#include <pshpack1.h>   // Assume byte packing throughout (32-bit processor)
#endif
```

Now, what that means is that I can't just set the `StructLayoutAttribute.Pack` property to a constant value.

I tried doing the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 8 : 1)]
public struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    public uint DevInst;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}
```

As expected, this fails with the following compilation error:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

I'd really like to avoid `#if` and setting up different compilation platforms, as opposed to `Any CPU`. Can I determine the packing of a C# structure at run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, packing is a compile-time concept, because it determines (among other things) the overall size of the type. That can't change at run-time.

In this case, if you're not willing to have separate builds for x86 and x64, you'll have to do the marshalling yourself. Thanks for @Hans Passant for a clean way to achieve this:

- Define two structures, say `SP_DEVINFO_DATA32` and `SP_DEVINFO_DATA64`,
- Define a method overload for each structure
- At run-time, select which structure to create and call the appropriate overload.

It would look something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA32 { /* stuff */ }
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA64 { /* stuff */ }

[DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
public static extern void Function(ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA32 data);

[DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
public static extern void Function(ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA64 data);

public void DoStuff()
{
    if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        var data = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA64 
        { 
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA64)) 
        };
        Function(ref data);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA32 
        {
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA32)) 
        };
        Function(ref data);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the IntPtr hack, you can simply declare an overload of the function that takes the other structure type.

Comment: The tweak offered by @HansPassant sounds reasonably elegant. Shall we add it to the answer?

Answer (score -1):

I have done in C++ and C#, both at x86 and x64, and I'll say that the "pack" doesn't have any effect on that structure, so you only need

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
```

At x86 both C++ and C# structures have a `sizeof`/`Marshal.SizeOf` of 28 bytes, at x64 of 32 bytes. If I create a

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public SP_DEVINFO_DATA a;
    public SP_DEVINFO_DATA b;
}
```

and in C

```
struct MyStruct
{
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA a;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA b;
};
```

the sizes are 56 at x86 and 64 at x64 (so exactly the double, zero padding). The difference in size between x86 and x64 is 4 bytes, so exactly the difference in size of the `IntPtr`.